# Animation: How to make a stateful widget depends on the widget parameter?

Tags: flutter, animation, statefulwidget

The `SoC` parameter of the widget is not available from the start.
So, I'd like my animation tween to actually takes the SoC when it is no longer null.

But because I construct my animation within the `initState()` I don't get a chance to do so.

What would be the best architecture for this widget?

```dart
class SocGaugeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double? soc;

  SocGaugeWidget({Key? key, required this.soc}) : super(key: key);

  State<SocGaugeWidget> createState() => _SocGaugeWidget();
}

class _SocGaugeWidget extends State<SocGaugeWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final Animation<double> animation;
  late final AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
 
    // == The animation
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    animation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: widget.soc ?? 10).animate(controller)
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          })
          ..addStatusListener((status) {
            if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
              controller.reverse();
            } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
              controller.forward();
            }
          });

    controller.forward();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Text("${animation.value}");
  }
}
```

Comment: when `soc` is null you can return sizedBox, also check before controller. I think better to check the usecase of this current widget. like `if(value!=null)SocGaugeWidget()`

Comment: Using `didUpdateWidget` lifecycle method to call `forward()` will start the animation everytime the widget configuration changes